# XSLT Spliting a string ,storing them in variables and output them

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**INPUT:**

stringToSplit = 251#999999999 (areaCode + # + pNumber)

**PROBLEM:**

I want to use XSLT  split that string (token = #) and store both areaCode and pNumber in different variables so I can then place them in my desired structure

**SOLUTION PSEUDOCODE:**

**XML Input**

```
<stringToSplit>351#911111111</stringToSplit>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="stringToSplit2" select="stringToSplit" />
        <xsl:variable name="items" select="tokenize($stringToSplit2, '#')"/> 

        <stringToSplit> 
            <xsl:value-of select="stringToSplit"/>
        </stringToSplit>

        <areaCode> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$items[1]"/>
        </areaCode>
        <pNumber> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$items[2]"/>
        </pNumber>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <areaCode> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(stringToSplit, '#')"/>
        </areaCode>
        <pNumber> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(stringToSplit, '#')"/>
        </pNumber>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**TESTING**

[Notepad++ faulty result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sELY.png) --> Notepad++ XML Tools (plugin) - XSL Transformation (feature) only works with XSLT 1.0

Comment: With only 2 values,  I would use simply `substring-before()` and `substring-after().`

Comment: Please always say what XSLT version you are using. I've added xslt-2.0 as a tag, hope that's correct.

Comment: My bad, indeed it's xslt-2.0

Comment: Does Notepad++ support XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, with only two values the simple solution is to use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <areaCode> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(stringToSplit, '#')"/>
        </areaCode>
        <pNumber> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(stringToSplit, '#')"/>
        </pNumber>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This is not only simpler, but also works in XSLT 1.0 (which apparently is the version you're using): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuT/1

Comment: It's my first time using StackOverflow but I've accepted both answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use one variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="items" select="tokenize($stringToSplit, '#')"/>` and then `<xsl:value-of select="$items[1]"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="$items[2]"/>` or set up three variables, the second and third based on the one I have already shown, i.e. `<xsl:variable name="item1" select="$items[1]"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="item2" select="$items[2]"/>`.

As already pointed out in a comment, your sample, with the suggestions made above, would look like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="stringToSplit2" select="stringToSplit" />
        <xsl:variable name="items" select="tokenize($stringToSplit2, '#')"/> 

        <stringToSplit> 
            <xsl:value-of select="stringToSplit"/>
        </stringToSplit>

        <areaCode> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$items[1]"/>
        </areaCode>
        <pNumber> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$items[2]"/>
        </pNumber>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuT

Comment: I tried your solution (solution implemented in the post description under "**SOLUTION SUDO CODE:**") . When apply the XSLT to my XML file I get: _"The transformation has generated empty document"_

Comment: @TiagoBarral You have a typo on line 5: you missed the final `t` in the variable's name. In addition, tokens are numbered from 1, not 0. And while I am at it, "sudo" is not a word.

Comment: @michael-hor257k Thanks for all the contributions :) . It works in ".NET XSLT Fiddle" but by some unknown reason when I try the exact same .xml and .xslt in Notepad++ using the XML Pluggin (XSL Transformation) I still get "The transformation has generated empty document"

Comment: @michael-hor257k I've updated the main post with your additions (not sure if it's healthy to update my first post or if there's a protocol to follow , like assigning dates and not altering the first post) with a picture showing the outcome under **TESTING**. Either way my problem seems to be solved, many thanks for the clarity and fast response :)

Comment: @TiagoBarral, to use XSLT 2 you need to use an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9, available in various versions (Java, .NET, C/C++) and editions. I don't know whether there is a plugin to use XSLT 2 in your editor.

Comment: @MartinHonnen after some investigation you right. My editor plugin only supports XSLT 1. All mysteries solved, thanks again :)